# IBM Watson Assistant: user input button label as text instead of click the button

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson

I'm using IBM Watson Assistant's option responses for my chatbot. I have put entity value "A" as the button label and the corresponding values are like "definition of A". However, when assistant display the option and button, if user input "A" as text instead of click the button, I cannot respond the correct message as for "definition of A".

Others have suggest me to set a separate node only for this entity "A", but I'm using the same button labels for several questions and are expecting different responses under different situation. Also, I have tried to use slots, but I want the assistant redirect user to another node with option responses instead of respond with certain text.

Can anyone give me some suggestion on this matter?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking. The option value is "definition of A" and the user is giving some other input? And the input is not recognized for "definition of A"?

Answer (score 0):

The others were right.  You can use the "A" entity in a new node.  You can re-use entities, the values are overridden when the user responds.  If this is not happening, you can handle it yourself by using a context variable to store their answers instead of an entity.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried this idea, but chatbot cannot deal with the situation when same button label appears in different question. E.g. "A" direct to "definition of A" in X question while "A" directs to "requirement for A" in Y question. How can i identify that user actually what to reach "definition of A" when input "A" as text response for X question?

Comment: @YuehuaTang Try not re-using the label same value for different questions. Maybe try A1 B1 C1 D1 A2 B2 C2 D2 etc.